# Is it considered bad practice to change the value of __proto__ of an object?

Tags: javascript

I was trying to reproduce this piece of code from a tutorial website

```
let animal = {
  eat() {
    this.full = true;
  }
};

let rabbit = {
  __proto__: animal
};

rabbit.eat();
```

I got this error "The '**proto**' property is deprecated". I have done a lot of research to find an alternative for '**proto**', but I end up thinking it is bad practice to do it. Here are my thoughts:

- the example above is not good in real life. Animal and rabbit should be classes instead of objects. Am I right?
- if the example was bad, what would be a good example in real life that needs to get/set **proto**?

Comment: `The use of __proto__ is controversial, and has been discouraged. It was never originally included in the EcmaScript language spec, but modern browsers decided to implement it anyway. It is deprecated in favor of Object.getPrototypeOf/Reflect.getPrototypeOf and Object.setPrototypeOf/Reflect.setPrototypeOf (though still, setting the [[Prototype]] of an object is a slow operation that should be avoided if performance is a concern).` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read all the reasons why this is bad practice [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

> Warning: Changing the [[Prototype]] of an object is, by the nature of how modern JavaScript engines optimize property accesses, a very slow operation, in every browser and JavaScript engine...
>
> Warning: While Object.prototype.**proto** is supported today in most browsers, its existence and exact behavior has only been standardized in the ECMAScript 2015 specification as a legacy feature...

And like you mentioned yourself, it's a deprecated feature. If you are learning ES6 then [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) are indeed the way to go here:

```
class Animal {
  eat() {
    this.full = true;
  }
}

class Rabbit extends Animal {}

const rabbit = new Rabbit();
rabbit.eat();
```

The Rabbit extends the `Animal.prototype`, which in itself always extends the `Object.prototype`.